# Get underflow notification from uhd sink in a gnuradio block

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, uhd

Is it possible to know, from a gnuradio OOT block, if underflow(s) occurred with a UHD sink block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the `UHD: USRP Async Msg Source`, or observing the tags on the output stream of the USRP Source.